# Remove dictionary from list of dictionaries if value has empty list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and within the dictionary is a list.

```
{
   "Credentials": [
      {
         "realName": "Mark Toga",
         "toolsOut": [
            "TL-482940",
            "TL-482940"
         ],
         "username": "291F"
      },
      {
         "realName": "Burt Mader",
         "toolsOut": [],
         "username": "R114"
      },
      {
         "realName": "Tim Johnson",
         "toolsOut": [
            "TL-482940"
         ],
         "username": "E188"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am attempting to parse this file so that it shows something like this:

Mark Toga: TL-482940, TL482940
Tim Johnson: TL-482940

Ommitting Burt Mader as he has no tools out.

I have it to a point where it displays the above with Burt Mader still ([GUI output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zge5.png))

Edit: Here is a printout of newstr6 rather than the GUI image. I do want the GUI for my application, but for ease of reading:

```
Mark Toga: 'TL-482940', 'TL-482940',
 Burt Mader: ,
 Tim Johnson: 'TL-482940'
```

Here is my current code (I'm sure there are many efficiency improvements, but I mostly care about ommitting the dictionary with the empty list.)

```
## importing libraries
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
import pprint

mainWin = Tk()
mainWin.geometry('400x480')
mainWin.title('Select Tooling')

with open('Inventory.json','r+') as json_file:
    data=json.load(json_file)
    credData = data['Credentials']
    noSID = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'username'} for d in credData]

    print(noSID)

    pp = pprint.pformat(noSID)
    ps = str(pp)

    newstr1 = ps.replace('[','')
    newstr2 = newstr1.replace(']','')
    newstr3 = newstr2.replace('{','')
    newstr4 = newstr3.replace('}','')
    newstr5 = newstr4.replace("'realName': '","")
    newstr6 = newstr5.replace("', 'toolsOut'","")

    text = Label(mainWin,text=newstr6)
    text.pack()

quitButton = Button(mainWin,text="Log Out",command=lambda:mainWin.destroy())
quitButton.pack()

mainWin.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need a GUI with `tkinter` to reproduce your problem. You can use `print()` statements to print the output you want, and that allows people who can't/don't want to see a GUI to replicate your problem. [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780). You don't want to display the person that has no tools checked out, but you don't really need to remove them from the list to do that. You're relying on `pprint` to convert a dictionary to a string, and then messing with that string. Instead, just build the string from scratch, and don't include the people with no tools checked out.

```
data=json.load(json_file)
credData = data['Credentials']

# Since you're the one creating the string, you can choose what you want to put in it
# No need to create a NEW dictionary without the username keys
outstr = ""
for person in credData:
    outstr += person['realName'] + ": " + ", ".join(person['toolsOut']) + "\n"

print(outstr)
```

This prints:

```
Mark Toga: TL-482940, TL-482940
Burt Mader: 
Tim Johnson: TL-482940
```

Now, since you want to ignore the persons that don't have any tools, add that condition.

```
outstr = ""
for person in credData:
    if person['toolsOut']:
        outstr += person['realName'] + ": " + ", ".join(person['toolsOut']) + "\n"

print(outstr)
```

And you get:

```
Mark Toga: TL-482940,TL-482940
Tim Johnson: TL-482940
```

`if person['toolsOut']` is identical to `if len(person['toolsOut']) == 0` because empty lists are [Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/843953)

If you *really* want to remove the elements of `credData` that have empty `toolsOut` keys, you can use this same condition in a list comprehension.

```
credData2 = [person for person in credData if person['toolsOut'])
```

Comment: I do not know if your are the one who downvoted my answer. But strickly considering the question title, my answer is correct

Comment: @BSP I didn't. If I had to guess why the person who did did, I'd say it's because there's no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your list of dictionaries by aplying certain condition. In this case, dict key `toolsOut` associated content should be asserted as `True`:

```
def process_data(list_of_dicts, field):
    res = []
    for item in list_of_dicts:
        if item[field]:
            res.append(item)
    return res

credData = process_data(data["Credentials"], "toolsOut")
```

Comment: Add more context explaining your answer prevents down voting. By doing so the quality of the answer increases and prevents flagging. As I see you commented elsewhere I have confidence you will make the proper adjustments. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the unwanted items when you load the "credential" list:

```
credData  = [d for d in data['Credentials'] if d.get("toolsOut")]
```

or you could have a separate variable for the filtered credentials

```
credWithTools = [d for d in credData if d.get("toolsOut")]
```